# Dynamic Tabs for ng-class

Tags: angularjs, tabs, ng-class

I am trying to change the active state of tabs that are created dynamically.  Depending on which value is selected, will determine which view I will see and will change the $location.  I this code and cannot get the state of the dynamically created tabs to change.  Need some guidence on what I am doing wrong.
Thank you 
Here is my code snippet

HTML

```
    <ul id="tabBarList">
        <li ng-class="{active: isActive('/list')}" ng-model="all"><a href="#/list"     id="newRequest" >All Requests</a></li>
        <li ng-class="{active: isActive()}" ng-click="getDetails(tabs.name, post.status)" ng-repeat="tabs in tabList"><a href=""  id="idNumber"># {{tabs.name}}</a><a href="" id="exitTab" ng-click="selectTab(tabs.name)" >x</a></li>
    </ul>


        <tr ng-repeat="post in posts">
        <td id="ticketId"><a id="listlink" href="" ng-click="addTab(post.ticketId, post.status)">{{post.ticketId}}</a></td>
        </tr>
```

Controller

```
$scope.isActive = function(path) {
            if($location.path() == path){
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
};
```

Function to get location for created tab

$scope.getResults = function(status){

```
    if( status == "Closed"){
    var path = "/list/closed";
    $location.path(path);

    $scope.getActive($location.path());

    }

    if( status == "Active"){

    }
}
```

$scope.tabList = [ ];
$scope.addTab = function(ticketId) {

```
            $scope.tabList.push({'name': ticketId });

        };
```

Comment: can you not use tabs directive from angular-ui, it already has feature you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shivali/j8h09d8y/1/)

And do changes like

`<ul id="tabBarList">
            <li ng-class="{active: isActive('list')}" ng-model="all"><a href="#/list"     id="newRequest" >All Requests</a></li>
           <li ng-class="{active: isActive(tabs.name)}" ng-click="getDetails(tabs.name, post.status)" ng-repeat="tabs in tabList"><a href="#/{{tabs.name}}"  id="idNumber"># {{tabs.name}}</a><a href="" id="exitTab" ng-click="selectTab(tabs.name)" >x</a></li>
</ul>`

`$scope.isActive = function(path) {
    if($location.path() == '/'+path){
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
    };`

Comment: your solution worked excellent, just a side note I was using templateHTML and I had to make my html template consistent on all the tabs lists.